# Add data from a file to an array

Tags: java

How do I put the values of column x in X, y in Y and clusternum in cluster array after I read the following data from a file.

The file has data as below

```
X      Y       Cluster
1.003   5.007   Cluster1
4.199   1.950   Cluster1
1.961   6.736   Cluster1
3.805   5.918   Cluster1
3.846   5.677   Cluster1
3.846   5.462   Cluster1
3.856   5.194   Cluster2
3.826   4.913   Cluster2
3.775   4.672   Cluster2
7.535   4.471   Cluster3
7.545   4.296   Cluster3
5.318   5.972   Cluster4
5.217   5.798   Cluster4
```

I have used 'random' to generate random numbers but need to put the data from the file.

```
String file = "Cluster.txt";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); 

  String st; 
  while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) 
    System.out.println(st);
```

```
List<Double> scores = new ArrayList<>();
Random random = new Random();
int Y = 20;
int X = 8;
for (int i = 0; i < Y; i++) {
    scores.add((double) random.nextDouble() * X);
}
```

Comment: Please add your current work (actual code) to the question, so others can help you to enhance that to achieve your goal.

Comment: @UdithGunaratna just added the code

Comment: @ManishOjha The code you posted does not even try to solve the problem